# Equal height inner divs using CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have markup as follows

```
<div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="description"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the title and body divs to have equal heights. So if title of first block is longer then the height of second title should match the height of first title. Same for description.
I am using `tailwind css` and tried using flexboxes and grids and I am not able to get this to work as expected. I see that this can't be done using flex but grids could be an option.
Currently I solved this using some jQuery that works. But it would be great if I could do this using CSS.
Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks

Comment: What's your CSS?

Comment: Please, show your CSS.

Comment: Sorry. I am using tailwind css. So no explicit css (only classes)and the markup is quite complex to put here without context. But basically what I have is markup like I added above.